# new to java - understanding an HTTP POST request

Tags: java, android, rest

I have been trying to understand the postData() method in the [following tutorial](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient).
My understanding of the code is:

- an nameValuePairs object, which contains some data is being sent over the internet to some web service located at this address: http://www.yoursite.com/script.php which will receive this nameValuePairs object

Comment: Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29). Nothing to do with Java - this is the HTTP protocol.

Comment: What is you don't understand exactly? What's the question?

Comment: ok so it is not java, but is it doing what i think it is doing ?

Comment: the question is, is my understanding of the code correct ?

Comment: if you pass an id in namevaluepair, u can get in php page like this $id= $_POST['id'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you want to send the age of a person to the webservice.

If you send data via GET the call of the webservice would be like this:

http://www.yoursite.com/script.php?age=18

If you send data via POST the call of the webservice would be like this:

http://www.yoursite.com/script.php

and the key-value arguments are integrated in the data stream of the request

So, to answer your question, no object will be sent,

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", "18"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

will integrate the key-value-list to the data stream of the request.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, ok, now I want to send real data to some real web service using key-value pair, obviously yoursite.com is not real, can you recommend a link that I can practice with ?

Comment: see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962495/where-to-find-free-public-web-services).

Comment: This isn't strictly speaking correct. A POST request is sent over the data stream not the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, basically... server gets that `name-value pair` and can process it as it wants ...

For example when logging into your email account, you are sending two `name-value pairs` - `username=your_username` and `password=your_password` ... after receiving, server checks if username you sent is correct and if the password is valid for given username, and then sends you to your account or throws a message that data you supplied is invalid.

It is not java specific. It is http protocol, that can be implemented in any other language.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, ok, now I want to send real data to some real web service, obviously yoursite.com is not real, can you recommend a link that I can practice with ?

Comment: @user3134565 For testing, try [this service](http://httpbin.org/), url to post would be `http://httpbin.org/post`.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass an id in like this,

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "20"));
```

In php page, you can get the value like this,

```
$id= $_POST['id'];
```